# RMarkdown flextable: Does as_image() work with rmarkdown::render()?

Tags: r, r-markdown, render, flextable, officedown

I want to insert an image into a flextable which works perfectly when using the knit button. However, I need to execute the code by calling `rmarkdown::render(input = "path_to_file/file.Rmd")`.

This generates the following error message:

> Error in save_kable(x = x, file = temp_png, ...) :
> argument "x" is missing, with no default

This is the YAML:

```
---
output: 
    officedown::rdocx_document
---
```

And this is a reproducable example:

````
```{r}
library(officer)
library(flextable)
library(officedown)

img.file <- file.path( R.home("doc"), "html", "logo.jpg" )

myft <- flextable( head(iris))

myft <- compose(myft, i = 1:3, j = 1,
  value = as_paragraph(as_image(src = img.file, width = .20, height = .15)))

ft <- autofit(myft)
ft
```
````

Comment: I am not able to reproduce, it generates the expected document. Can you add your session info? I don't understand why `save_kable` is mentioned in the error...

Answer (score 2):

I tested your codes and it worked fine. As David Gohel mentioned, `save_kable` error does not refer to your reproducable example. Maybe you have other code lines remaining in your Rmd. file that cause the issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response and you were right. I had included `library(kableExtra)` before which was causing the problem. @DavidGohel When adding this library, the `save_kable` error occurs.